# Expect ssh and create directory

Tags: ssh, expect

I'm having some trouble with expect.

I'm trying to ssh onto another machine and then create a directory on that machine.

Right now this is what my code looks like:

```
spawn ssh username@ipAddress
expect "password"
send "password"
file mkdir directoryName
```

That code is giving me a "permission denied".

When I try replacing

```
file mkdir directoryName
```

with

```
send "mkdir directoryName"
```

There's no error, but it doesn't make a file.
Thanks.

Comment: Try sending a carriage return as part of the command: `send "mkdir directoryName\r"`

Comment: Doesn't quite work either.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you :-

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout -1
spawn -noecho bash -c "ssh username@serveraddress 'cd /user/bill/work;<your=command>'"
expect {
-re "assword:"{
    send "mypassword/r"
}eof{
    wait
}
```

You must send the command inside `ssh` as it will run on remote machine.

Explanation for above script :-

`set timeout -1`will set this loop in infinite (but it will exit once `spawn` process is finished.

`-re` will match regex for `assword:`

`eof` will wait until `spawn` is finish.

Answer (score 0):

After sending `mkdir` command, wait for `eof` to happen.

```
send "mkdir directoryName\r"
expect eof
```